# Can you generate password from a decrypted and encrypted bip38 keys?

Tags: wallet-recovery, bitaddress.org

I made 5 bip38  wallets on bitaddress.org all with the same password.  all the keys generated started with number 6.

I loaded bitcoin on to each of these addresses , and later decrypted one of them with the key and password, which gave me the key starting with number 5, so I then swept the address.

A few months later I forgot the password with bitcoin still on the other addresses. I still have the key starting with 6 and the key starting with 5 for the wallet I decrypted, so would I be able to somehow use these keys to generate the password? Its not much btc but I could do with the cash now. any ideas anybody?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are effectively asking whether there is a "known plaintext attack" on AES256.

A quick Google search suggests there isn't.